# Angular Lazy loading Module Reload Not working

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have implemented lazy loading module, and Inside the module's routing I'm loading the child components,

Like this.

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: CustomerListComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "child",
        component: CustomerChildComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

And Inside the CustomerListComponent's OnInit I'm navigate to the child component as below

```
export class CustomerListComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private router: Router) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate(["customers/child"]);
  }
}
```

My issue is If I click Menu/Button which is redirecting/loading to this module, the first time working fine, and Once this module loaded, again If click the same Menu/Button, it's not reloading/redirecting up to the child component as like this '/customers/child' instead it is load as 
'/customers

So My issues is , at first time I'm able to see both components Customers and Child also, but on the next click I'm able to see only Customers component only.

In My real time scenario, I keeping a tabs and one grid inside the customer component, that grid should be available to all the tabs,

In the router-outlet in Customers component I'm loading the child components.

So In the second click I'm seeing only the gird but the child component.

I have tried to simulate the problem with in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n1y4uw)

In that stackblitz you can notice, On Clicking the Customers button at second time, The child will be removed from the routing.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding below code in the constructor

```
this.subscriptions.add(router.events.subscribe((evt: any) => {
  if (evt.url === '/customers') {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/customers/child');
  }
}));
```